# Blender 3.0 preferences problem

Tags: customization

I've been having this problem since I downloaded blender 3.0 (Final Release). Whenever I try to save my preferences, it shows: "Cannot save preferences" and "Cannot save old file with @".

Due to this problem, I cannot properly use any addons or any other preferences in blender 3.0. I have tried reinstalling blender, but the issue persists. I do not have any blender files with @ in them.

Please help. Thanks in advance (:
[image]

Comment: I cannot remember where preferences are stored, but perhaps the folder or file is not writable permission.  It sounds like it appended a '@' onto the filename.

Comment: @james_t so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: You haven't said what operating system you're running Blender under, but Blender's directory layout is detailed [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html) which might help.

Comment: @JohnEason I'm running Windows 11 pre-release version

Comment: @JohnEason actually I don't understand what am I supposed to do

Comment: As far as I know W11 isn't any different to W10 as far as folder permissions and locations are concerned so I'd try to find the userpref.blend file by typing '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\' into the Windows Run dialog box and then opening the 'config' directory that it should list.  In W10 Professional that opens fine here so I doubt it's a permission problem. I suspect you'll have to delete the 'userpref.blend' file there to get things running again but that may well delete any layout and theme options you have set up.

Comment: Thanks! I will try doing that.

Comment: If John Eason's suggestion above doesn't work, I'd recommend bypassing Window's over-protectiveness by completely uninstalling Blender 3.0, making a directory C:\Other Program Files\ , and installing Blender 3.0 in there.  Although doing that with potential malware can be disastrous, I've resolved similar issues with other trusted (IMHO) software in earlier Window's versions back to Vista.

Comment: @Kickair8p Yes I've done that for some applications but Blender's setting file are saved to the user's AppData folder by default which is where the problem appears to lie here so I doubt it would make any difference in this case. In fact Blender is installed on my 'D' drive here and the settings file is still saved on 'C' by default.

Comment: @JohnEason I tried what you said, and it turned out that the userpref file was 'blend@', but even after I deleted it the error persists.

Comment: @KickAir8p Maybe the problem is that I downloaded blender from the Microsoft Store, so instead, it might work if I downloaded it from the website

Comment: Well, my problem was actually solved by uninstalling the Microsoft store blender 3.0 version and downloading the windows version of 3.0 from blender's website. Anyways, thanks for your time and help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the solution was to download blender 3.0 from its website. I originally downloaded blender 3.0 from the Microsoft Store, which was causing the "BLEND@" file problem. Uninstalling the Microsoft Store version and downloading blender from blender's website solved the problem.

Also, thanks for John Eason's and KickAir8p's help in the comments. The solutions didn't solve my issue but are the primary solutions for most problems like these.

Comment: How odd! The '@' character is certainly illegal in windows filenames so I'm not sure what could have caused it. At least you seem to be back in business now!