# Is there a trick to getting Blender to save my undo preferences?

Tags: customization

I've used Blender for about a week.

Every time I open a file, I have to change the undo preference from 32 to 256. It never saves this preference permanently. After using it for a few hours, it will change back to the default 32.

How can I get Blender to save this option?

Comment: What's your OS? Are you using windows? Did you install blender from the Microsoft store? This happened to me once but it was solved when I downloaded blender from the website. Is this happening for all settings or only on undo? Maybe you don't have enough memory to store this many undos? Maybe this could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248272/blender-3-0-preferences-problem

Answer (score 2):

The hamburger menu in the bottom left corner.

[image]

Auto-save preferences may not be checked, but you can also manually save.

Comment: Hi. I just checked and it's checked. I just noticed I don't even have to close it. Just use it for a few hours, and it reverts back. :/

Comment: Oh shoot.  Well that shouldn't happen, I would say.  Is your OS not allowing you to write the new file?

Comment: Hi I'm using Windows 10. I didn't care for 11. I backed down a couple months ago. I wonder if that might be the culprit?

Comment: In File Explorer go to %appdata% -> Blender Foundation and go to your current version's folder and maybe just rename it.  It should create a new default prefs file the next time you open Blender.